# Use multiple different implementations of library in one program (unit tests)

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine, static-linking

During writing of unit tests I found that I need to implement "dummy" version of some library in one of unit tests. However the same library is used in its standard version in other unit tests. The obvious way how to solve this issue is to compile unit tests as two (or more) standalone programs (executables).

However, this solution does not satisfy my ambition ;-). I think that there should be a way how to compile one library against another library "statically" (in sense of "static function"). In other words: some used libraries are encapsulated in my library but the rest of program uses another implementation of used libraries.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Our tests are build on unity and compiled with gcc and cmake.